# Why do I get a "no implicit conversion of false into string"

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner in programming and as a fun little excercise tried making the word-game jotto, but as of right now it only works if you answer correctly the first time. What I want is for the program to tell me how many of the letters, in the word I guessed, are in the right answer, but not what the letters are. I thought I had it but
 "if answer.include? word_array[iterations] == true" gives me an error that says no implicit conversion of alse into string

```
def jotto()
    file_content = File.readlines("words.txt")
    i = 0
    new_array = []
        while i < file_content.length 
            temp_str = file_content[i]
            if temp_str.length == 4
                new_array << temp_str
            end
            i = i + 1
        end

    answer = new_array[rand(new_array.length)]

    puts(answer)

    puts "Guess the secret word"

    word = gets

    word_array = []

    word_array << word

    i = 0

        while answer != word
            iterations = 0
            w = 0
            while iterations <= word.length

                if answer.include? word_array[iterations] == true
                    w = w + 1
                end
                iterations = iterations + 1
            end
        puts("That's not correct but there are " + w + " of the same letters")
        end
    print("Yes! " + answer + " is the right answer!")

end
```

jotto()

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Don’t put things like “(ruby)” in your title. That’s what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Tiw pointed out your first issue but there are several.

Here is an updated version of your code with some comments explaining why the change was made.

I also included a more ruby like version.

```
def jotto()
    file_content = File.readlines("words.txt")
    i = 0
    new_array = []
        while i < file_content.length 
            temp_str = file_content[i].chomp  #added
            if temp_str.length == 4
                new_array << temp_str
            end
            i = i + 1
        end

    answer = new_array[rand(new_array.length)]

    puts(answer)

    puts "Guess the secret word"

    # you need to get the word from the user inside the while loop.
    # word = gets

    # word_array = []

    # word_array << word  # This adds the word to an array of strings .. you want to turn the string into an array of characters

    #i = 0  # not used
        # added
        word = nil
        while answer != word
            #added
            word = gets.chomp
            word_array = word.chars # see comment above
            iterations = 0
            w = 0
            while iterations < word.length  # was <=

                if answer.include? word_array[iterations]  # == true
                    w = w + 1
                end
                iterations = iterations + 1
            end
        puts("That's not correct but there are " + w.to_s + " of the same letters") if word != answer # there are better ways.
        end
    print("Yes! " + answer + " is the right answer!")

end
jotto()
```

A more ruby like way of doing things

```
def jotto()
    answer_list = File.readlines("words.txt").map { |line| line.strip } # map each read line into an array of strings without any whitespace
    answer = answer_list.sample  # get a random element 
    puts answer  #for debug only
    puts "Guess the secret word"

    loop do
        guess = gets.strip 
        break if guess == answer  # exit the loop if correct 
        # map each char in answer to an array of true/false depending on if it matches the guess position
        matched_positions = answer.chars.each_with_index.map { |char ,index| char == guess[index] } 
        number_of_matching_positions = matched_positions.count(true) # count the number of true entires (positions that matched)
        puts("That's not correct but there you did match #{number_of_matching_positions} positions - try again")
    end
    puts "Yes! " + answer + " is the right answer!"
end

jotto()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I really struggled with it but I see where I was wrong now, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Grammar error,

```
if answer.include? word_array[iterations] == true
```

is redundent, as well as not quoted right.

What you were trying was:

```
if answer.include?(word_array[iterations]) == true
```

But Ruby reads it as:

```
if answer.include? (word_array[iterations] == true)
```

But the right way is:

```
if answer.include? word_array[iterations]
```

No need to check if it's true, since `include?` will give you `true` or `false`, and already can apply to `if`.

For example:

```
"abcd".include? 'a'
#=> true
"abcd".include? 'f'
#=> false
"abcd".include?('a') == true
#=> true
```

As you can see, when you compare `true == true`, it still give you a `true`, so why bother to compare them?

About the `nil` conversion error, I think it's because this:

```
while iterations <= word.length
```

should change to

```
while iterations < word.length
```

Since the max index of a string is the length of the string minus one. (0 to length-1).

Also, `gets` will input an extra `\n` with it, replace it with `gets.chomp`.